# optimize finding value with max time in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like

```
history = [
    {'val':234, 'when':1691884800},
    {'val':254, 'when':1692230400},
    {'val':212, 'when':1691366400},
]
```

I need to get 'val' where value of 'when' is highest

For now I am doing it like:

```
maxval = [his['val'] for his in history if his['when']== max([his['when'] for his in history])][0]
```

However it is very inefficient and takes a lot of time when I have to go through ~300K of such dictionaries.
is there any way to optimize this part?

Comment: Comparing the suggested methods using 300k random dictionaries: using `max(history, key = ...)` is the fastest, closely followed by using a `for` loop (+8%). `sort` is slower again (+500%) while your original code does not complete within a reasonable time frame.

Comment: The reasoning behind this is pretty simple:
`for` and `max` have a time complexity of O(n), `sort` has a worst case time complexity of O(n*logn), your code has i think time complexity of O(n^3)

Answer (score 5):

Just use [`key` keyword argument for `max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

```
>>> max(history, key=lambda h: h['when'])['val']
254
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using a single for loop?
Tested the time delta of for loop and your code, and found for loop is better.

```
import datetime

history = [{'val':234, 'when':1691884800},{'val':254, 'when':1692230400}] * 5000 #List with 10K items
#print(history)


# For Loop
###########################################################################

start = datetime.datetime.now()
max_val=0
max_when=0
for his in history:
    if his['when'] > max_when:
        max_val = his['val']
        max_when = his['when']

end = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = end-start      
print("Simple for loop time delta : ", delta)
print("Max val :", max_val)


#Your code
###################################################################################
start = datetime.datetime.now()
max_val = [his['val'] for his in history if his['when']== max([his['when'] for his in history])][0]
end = datetime.datetime.now() 
delta = end-start          
print("Your code time delta :", delta)
print("Max val :", max_val)
```

> output

```
Simple for loop time delta :  0:00:00.001998
Max val : 254
Your code time delta : 0:00:04.266999
Max val : 254
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this optimized code in which the maximum value of 'when' and the corresponding 'val' is found in just one iteration through dictionary:

```
history = [
    {'val':234, 'when':1691884800},
    {'val':254, 'when':1692230400},
    {'val':212, 'when':1691366400},
]

max_when = float('-inf')
max_val = None

for his in history:
    if his['when'] > max_when:
        max_when = his['when']
        max_val = his['val']

print("Max 'val' with max 'when':", max_val)
```